# Mapping k-means cluster centers and origins (measuring k-means accuracy)

Tags: r, clustering, k-means, supervised-learning, model-evaluation

Say I generate a dataset $X$: the first $i$ samples follow $x_i\sim N(\mu_1,\Sigma_1^2)$, the next j samples follow $N(\mu_2,\Sigma_2^2)$ and the last $l$ samples from $N(\mu_3,\Sigma_3^2)$. Naturally, I denote the clusters $(1,2,3)$ by the order of creation.

When using `kmeans(X,3)$clusters` I get the predicted assignment of the samples, but here lies the problem: `kmeans` might enumerate the clusters differently, for example set $N(\mu_2,\Sigma_2^2)$ as cluster#3 and vice versa. In this situation, I cannot compare the 'original' cluster assignment (say $(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)$) with the predicted one (say $(1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2)$). this will result with only 20% accuracy, even though the actual accuracy is 100%.

Any ideas of how to map the centroids or measure the accuracy of the `kmeans` performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you start looking at the [`clusteval` package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clusteval/clusteval.pdf), which offers various ways of evaluating clusterings.

For instance, `cluster_similarity()` measures the similarity between two clusterings by looping over all pairs of points and assessing whether they are assigned to the same cluster under both clusterings. Of course, this is agnostic to labelings of clusters. And one of the two clusterings could be the "gold standard" labels you may already have in [supervised-learning](/questions/tagged/supervised-learning).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Hungarian matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to find the best match of clusters.

The usual approach (see literature, and Wikipedia, on cluster evaluation, rather than reinventing the wheel) is to work with pairs of points, and the property if they are both in the same cluster, or different clusters. This reduces it to a two case problem (same, or different).

In your scenario, Gaussian Mixture Modeling will usually work much better...